# PHP - How to loop 2 set of arrays and mix them together?

Tags: mysql, arrays, loops, foreach

I'm having a problem on looping arrays and mix them up as a new set of data. The first set of array is room id. Another set is range of date. I'd like to loop each day in a range with room ids in array.

**Here's my resources:**

```
$_rid=array("5","6");
$date_range=getDays('2012-11-30','2012-12-05');
$_sid=md5(time());
```

**Get dates between two days function:**

```
function getDays($strDateFrom,$strDateTo) {
  // takes two dates formatted as YYYY-MM-DD and creates an
  // inclusive array of the dates between the from and to dates.

  // could test validity of dates here but I am already doing
  // that in the main script

  $aryRange=array();

  $iDateFrom=mktime(1,0,0,substr($strDateFrom,5,2),     substr($strDateFrom,8,2),substr($strDateFrom,0,4));
  $iDateTo=mktime(1,0,0,substr($strDateTo,5,2),     substr($strDateTo,8,2),substr($strDateTo,0,4));

  if ($iDateTo>=$iDateFrom) {
    array_push($aryRange,date('Y-m-d',$iDateFrom)); // first entry

    while ($iDateFrom<$iDateTo) {
      $iDateFrom+=86400; // add 24 hours
      array_push($aryRange,date('Y-m-d',$iDateFrom));
    }
  }
  return $aryRange;
}
```

**So I wrote:**

```
foreach($_POST[vid] as $_vidz){//5-6
    foreach($date_range as $val0){  
    //get cost from villas_rate each date
    $sql_rCost="select vr_cost from villas_rate where vr_id='$_vidz'";
    //echo $sql_rCost."<hr />";
    $result_rCost=mysql_db_query($dbname,$sql_rCost);
    while($rec_rCost=mysql_fetch_array($result_rCost)){
        $_rCostDBcost=explode("-",str_replace(",","",$rec_rCost['vr_cost']));   
            $_rate=$_rCostDBcost[$_rtype-1];//rate starts with 0
            $_date=$val0;
            $sql_cBk="insert into booking_customer values('','$_sid','$_vidz','$_rate','$_agc','$_date')";
            echo $sql_cBk."<br />";             
        }
    }
}
```

**The result**
It should be good by the result. But it only loop only for one value in an array $_rid=5.

```
insert into booking_customer values('','e1eb3f2e2c0fe99780c0354fa699a827','5','2012-11-30')
insert into booking_customer values('','e1eb3f2e2c0fe99780c0354fa699a827','5','2012-12-01')
insert into booking_customer values('','e1eb3f2e2c0fe99780c0354fa699a827','5','2012-12-02')
insert into booking_customer values('','e1eb3f2e2c0fe99780c0354fa699a827','5','2012-12-03')
insert into booking_customer values('','e1eb3f2e2c0fe99780c0354fa699a827','5','2012-12-04')
insert into booking_customer values('','e1eb3f2e2c0fe99780c0354fa699a827','5','2012-12-05')
```

Comment: Nice [sql injection hole](http://bobby-tables.com). Hope you enjoy having your server pwn3d. And you might want to read up on the [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) object, which'd saving you a LOT of the pointless date/string manipulation you're doing.

Comment: @MarcB, If you see any problem or having a chance of improvement. Please don't hesitate to show me some lines of example codes. Thnx

Answer (score 0):

May be you used input's names like  `<input name="vid" .. <input name="vid" ..` in your HTML form and in this case you have trouble here:

```
foreach($_POST[vid] as $_vidz)
```

You should using names with `[]` like `<input name="vid[]" .. <input name="vid[]" ..`

Or in `villas_rate` didn't exists records with `vr_id = 6`

Comment: Ivan, Thank you for your suggestion. I was wrong sending vid value from a previous form.